# fontfactory.getfont type initialization error asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-5, itext

I get an error at this line of code and I used reflector to go through the dll and the function fontfactory.getfont works. Is it because of the system architecture? The application is built for AnyCPU. Thank you

```
static readonly Font Font7Bold = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 7, Font.BOLD);
```

Comment: If this is your exact code then `getInstance` should be `GetInstance` because C# is case-sensitive.

Comment: It doesn't show any other option than getInstance, also it works as it is in MVC 2.0. Looking into that I also get an error at "DefaultPdfGenerator pdf = new DefaultPdfGenerator();" as a type initilaizer. I am thinking it is the iText dll error that is not liking something in MVC 5.0. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Looking at the [current code base](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/PdfWriter.cs#l630) there's no lowercase version of that method. If you truly have that method then you might be using an unofficial build of iTextSharp. What version are you running? Also, to the best of my knowledge the class `DefaultPdfGenerator` is not part of iTextSharp. iTextSharp has zero care about ASP.Net, MVC, Web Forms, etc, regardless of their versions. It is a fully-managed platform-agnostic (except Windows Store) library.

Comment: The actual problem is here   "static readonly Font Font7Bold = FontFactory.getFont("Arial", 7, Font.BOLD);" I am getting an initialization error here.

Comment: Once again, there's no `getFont()` method, only `GetFont()`. In the process of upgrading from MVC 2 to MVC 5 did you also upgrade from iTextSharp 4.x to 5.x?

Comment: I am using reflector to go through the DLL and it shows that FontFactory class has getFont methods. Please see this http://i.imgur.com/ujWf0sV.png?1  and http://i.imgur.com/HhgWoon.png?1

Comment: That helps a lot actually! iTextSharp is currently on 5.5.6 which is the only recommended version to use. Some people don't like the AGPL license and prefer the previous 4.1.6 version which was MPL/LGPL but this is discouraged and those people should probably have their lawyers [read this](http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq). You, however, are using a _very_ old version, 1.4.6.2 that [dates to 2006](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/14) which was _nine years ago_ and I don't think you can even find it online anymore! Since you are already upgrading MVC I think this would be a good time to upgrade iText.

Comment: I have upgraded iTextSharp to the current version. Thanks for the help.